# webView app with personalized push notifications?

Tags: android, webview, push-notification

I have a webview App, with OneSignal push notifications..that's ok if you want to send "general" notifications or "segmented" but what I want is that when a user get a new message in her account he get a notification about that new message.

How can I do this in a webView app?

My approach:
I think that the APP shoul get in some way the account ID of the user and every 2 minutes check if that ID has a new message.

but how can I do this?